# Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 context menus broken

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, I've noticed most context menus no longer show highlights.  
 There are also other issues in some toolbar menus (e.g. Roxterm). For context, I'm using LXDE. 
Firefox:

[image: firefox broken context menu]

Roxterm (both toolbar menu and context menu broken):

[image: roxterm broken toolbar menu and context menu]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my GTK theme was broken, simply switching to any other theme did the trick.

Specifically on an LXLE installation, I ran `lxappearance` and chose another theme.

For other distros, simply go to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and edit `gtk-theme-name`.